# loading dynamic library path error in mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, shared-libraries

I am now building a dynamic library and an command line illustration program that uses this dynamic library. The library and the illustration program are in the same folder:

```
/user/xxx/develop/debug/libdynamic.dylib
/user/xxx/develop/debug/illustration
```

When the illustration program can work very well in my computer, I send the illustration program as well as the dynamic library to my colleague and he will run the illustration program in his computer. However, every time he runs the illustration program in the command window, the program also reminds that it can not load the `libdynamic.dylib` as it tries to find the library in `/user/xxx/develop/debug/`, which is unavailable in my colleague's computer. I was wondering what I should do. Many thanks.

EDIT:
The output using otool for the illustration program is as follows:

```
 /Users/xxx/develop/debug/libdynamic.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)

    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.18.0)

    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Comment: Sorry you need `otool -L /user/xxx/develop/debug/illustration` to see where it thinks the `dylib` lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `illustration` where to find `libdynamic.dylib` which you can do post-build using `install_name_tool` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html)). You'll want to set the new path to `@executable_path/libdynamic.dylib`, with (something like):

```
$ install_name_tool -change /user/xxx/develop/debug/libdynamic.dylib \
  @executable_path/libdynamic.dylib \
  /user/xxx/develop/debug/illustration
```

(the exact *old name* value to pass to `install_name_tool` will depend on what it's currently set to, which can be determined using `otool -L /user/xxx/develop/debug/illustration`).

One way to avoid this nonsense (and the way I do it myself) is to use the `-install_name` linker option:

```
$(BINDIR)/libdynamic.dylib: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -dynamiclib -current_version $(MAJOR_MINOR_VERSION) \
        -compatibility_version $(MAJOR_MINOR_VERSION) \
        -install_name @executable_path/libdynamic.dylib \
        $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

(`Makefile` fragment taken from [here](https://github.com/trojanfoe/ChessCore/blob/master/src/Makefile)).